# Syncing data between sqlite and mongo using meteor, cordova

Tags: mongodb, sqlite, cordova, meteor, synchronization

I am developing a hybrid Cordova app (but only for Android platform) using Meteor.

App should have offline support, in a way that a user can add objects that are stored offline, in a SQLite database, and after the user connects to Internet, sync the data with server (Mongo database).

Problem is a can't find any solution for synchronisation. 
I have looked at GroundDB that provided the mechanism for synchronization I need, but stored data in localStorage which doesn't provide enough storage. In newer versions it doesn't provide sync mechanism, only cashing.

Do you have any suggestions or experience with this type of problem? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at LokiJS, which is in a high performance JS database, with features to sync to Mongo.

I haven't used it myself, but from looking at the site, it may do what you need. http://lokijs.org/#/

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out [MongOGX](https://github.com/globules-io/MongOGX) which is a Javascript "clone" of mongo for the front end